# Gatsby 3 "Path" argument must be of type string

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm attempting to upgrade from Gatsby 2 to 3. I removed all dependencies from `package.json` and installed Gatsby. I'm currently trying to run `gatsby develop`, but I get the error:

'The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object'

Any idea how to get around this? I'm not sure what all I need to share, but here's my `gatsby-config.js`.

```
// Gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata,
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        [],
        extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Tyler's Blog`,
        short_name: `TylersBlog`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#ffffff`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `content/favicon.svg`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `package-lock.json` and generate it again by `npm install`. Run a `gatsby clean` after that.

In addition, without knowing the `siteMetadata`  object structure it's difficult to guess if there's something wrong there but maybe your need to:

```
// Gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata.siteMetadata,
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Tyler's Blog`,
        short_name: `TylersBlog`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#ffffff`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `content/favicon.svg`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

I've also removed the empty options array.